# terraform give all values of a map default value?

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to give my map some default value ?

```sh
variable "project_var" {
  type        = map
  #default     = {}
  default      = { default: 'false'}
}
```

so that when I pass this var to a module with lets say 2 other values

```sh
project_var = { "project_a" : true, "project_b" : false }
```

but inside the module the resource will iterate over 10 other 'projects', can I give other that I didn't specify in my map a false value ?, for string that's easy what about a map?

Comment: You would have to do this in a `locals` block.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to define a default value for each element in a map, but given you have a default map specified, you can merge that with your user provided map to get a similar end result.

```
project_var = { "project_a" : true, "project_b" : false }
default_project_map = {"project_a" : false, "project_b" : false, "project_c" : false}
merge(default_project_map , project_var )
```

result:

```
{"project_a" : true, "project_b" : false, "project_c" : false}
```

References:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/merge.html